# when using assertion in ranges, getting failure?

Tags: groovy

I've seen some examples for ranges.

assert (0.0 .. 1.0).contains(0.5)

I would expecte True for this but I am getting false for this?

Any clue why this assertion failed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `groovy.lang.Range` is a `List` of `Comparable` values, two in this case. That's why `List.contains` returns `false` for `0.5`. What you want instead is `Range.containsWithinBounds`.

Comment: Thanks now i got.. i was expecting the range will for floats.. but it is not. by default it is taking step size 1.